# How to serve HTML from multiple JS, CSS directory in nginx

Tags: javascript, nginx, hosting

My directory structure is -

```
project
|----theme
|    |----css
|    |----images
|    |----js
|
|----pages
|    |----css
|    |----images
|    |----js
|    |----index.html
|
|----libraries
|    |----lib1
|    |     |----lib1.js
|    |    
|    |----lib2
|    |     |----lib2.js
```

and my nginx/sites-available config is-

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  root /home/ubuntu/project/pages;
  index index.html;
  server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

  location ~* \.(js|jpg|png|css)$ {
    root /home/ubuntu/project;   -----(A)
  }
}
```

I have references to files in "theme" and "libraries" from pages/index.html.
But the console outputs 404 error when trying to load these files.
How can I correctly serve these files?

If I edit and append "/pages" for root in (A), "pages" JS are served but then again files in "theme" and "libraries" are not found (shows 404 error in console).

Comment: what are your urls likes? The ones which give 404

Comment: The URL is of the format - http://example.com/js/customjs/script_file.js . The file exists as "pages/js/customjs/script_file.js" (the file name is in snake case).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `try_files` to try different locations

```
location ~* \.(js|jpg|png|css)$ {
  root /home/ubuntu/project;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /pages$uri /theme$uri =404;
}
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: The issue is unable to reach files from theme and libraries directory, as per my structure.